# What red tape might arise when crossing borders in a rental car (Macedonia to Croatia)?

Tags: car-rentals, land-borders, traffic, balkans, kosovo

I will be renting in Skopje, Macedonia and dropping the car in Zagreb, Croatia. I am aware the cost is high, but I just want to make sure I won't have any trouble at the border.

What costs might arise, and what might I need to have (besides a passport) at each border?

In addition, how long might the wait be to cross?

The borders I plan to cross are:

- Macedonia - Kosovo
- Kosovo - Albania
- Albania - Montenegro
- Montengro - Bosnia
- Bosnia - Croatia

Comment: Your question about how long the wait is should probably be a separate question.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai not to mention that the answer will be different for different border crossings, for different times of year, for different days, and for different times of day.

Comment: In addition to passports, you'll need the car's documents, including the rental agreement and the international insurance card (a.k.a. "green card").

Answer (score 1):

You will of course Need a passport (or ID card if a European citizen), as well as all documents the rental company gives you. It's also highly recommended to ask the company for a green Card (which might cost extra) to avoid having to buy local insurance at the border: however, it's not valid for Kosovo